# How to integrate over a triangle in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, integral

let's consider a two dimensional fonction **f(x,y)** 
and tree points A,B,C with ABC a triangle 
and i want to integrate the function **f** over the triangle ABC,
is there a way to do that in matlab?
thank you.

Comment: the answer i want is the volume of the function f(x,y)
in the triangle ABC, with A=(A_x, A_y), B=(B_x, B_y) and C=(C_x, C_y).

Comment: and also the function f(x,y) isn't always equal to 1

Comment: Please show the code you have.

Comment: +thewaywewalk
here is my code: http://pastebin.com/NuXzeLSs

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new function `h(x,y)`, that returns `f(x,y)` if `(x,y)` is inside the polygon, and `0` otherwise.

For instance:

```
A = [0, 0];
B = [0, 5];
C = [5, 0];

triangleX = [A(1) B(1) C(1)];
triangleY = [A(2) B(2) C(2)];

f = @(x,y) (1);
h = @(x,y) (inpolygon(x, y, triangleX, triangleY) .* f(x,y));

q = integral2(h, min(triangleX), max(triangleX), min(triangleY), max(triangleY)
              'Method', 'iterated')
```

Outputs (which may be close enough for you):

```
q =

  12.500070877352647
```

And another function:

```
f = @(x,y) (x .* y);
q = integral2(@foo, min(triangleX), max(triangleX), min(triangleY), max(triangleY), 
              'Method', 'iterated')

q =

  26.042038561947592
```

---

Notice that the [integral2 documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral2.html) states:

> When integrating over nonrectangular regions, the best performance and
>   accuracy occurs when ymin, ymax, (or both) are function handles. Avoid
>   setting integrand function values to zero to integrate over a
>   nonrectangular region. If you must do this, specify 'iterated' method.

So it'll be better if instead of using the above solution, you write two functions that given an `x` coordinate, give you the minimal and maximal `y` coordinates of the polygon (triangle).

Comment: thank you for you suggestion +Itay,
i am using the integration over a triangle to calculate the elements of a vector.
when i used your code the result is slow

Comment: and for A=[0.7265    1.9468], B=[0.6930    2.0000] and C=[0.6617 1.9468]
it gives me this warning:
Warning: Minimum step size
reached near x = 1.94678.
There may be a
singularity, or the
tolerances may be too
tight for this problem. 

Warning: The integration
was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

I found the correct answer, 
thanks to this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/954409/double-integral-over-an-arbitrary-triangle

```
function r = intm2(f, t)
% f: function 
% t: three points of a triangle
% r: integration of f over t
a = t(1,:);
b = t(2,:);
c = t(3,:);

jg = abs((b(1)-a(1))*(c(2)-a(2))-(c(1)-a(1))*(b(2)-a(2)));
ftilda = @(u,v) f(a(1)+u*(b(1)-a(1))+v*(c(1)-a(1)), a(2)+u*(b(2)-a(2))+v*(c(2)-    a(2)));

fy = @(x) 1-x;
r = jg * integral2(ftilda, 0,1, 0,fy);

end
```